# SSIS to collect index usage

Tags: sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrEWK.png)
I am trying to collect the index usage for 1 server out of 70 of them. I declared 2 variables and did this but I m not able to move further. Please help.

Comment: This post is a disaster and should be removed. The question and answer are not anywhere near standards and most likely never will be. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was quite an easy task as I figured out how to create a dynamic connection.
1) create variable databasename
2)create variable database object 
3) use that object in the sql task to store the list of databases and link that object to the foreach loop to go over each of the databases.
4) drag a data flow task 
5) create two connection managers. dynamic and static
6) use dynamic conn to connect the server so that you can list all the databases and pull them to foreach loop one by one to collect whatever you want( index usage, tables and so on)
7) Drag OLEDB source and destination and configure them as needed. Use dynamic connection to the execute SQL Task and the OLEDB source so that they work dynamically.
8) For the OLEDB destination use static connection that connects to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

Your connections are not dynamically set.
Please set the ServerName and DatabaseName dynamically using loop variable

Comment: that is what I am not able to figure out

Comment: Hmmm Looks you are new to SSIS. Google it out https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/dynamic-db-connection-ssis-tom%C3%A1%C5%A1-pri%C5%A1tic

Comment: Thanks again. Any other link to use ssis to "loop over all the databases inside a server to collect index usage"?

Comment: Thanks I was able to figure out. Thanks for the link.